# Downloading txt file from website android

Tags: java, android

I am trying to make program that can download *.txt* file from my website and save it on the phone, I found this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3028306/download-a-file-with-android-and-showing-the-progress-in-a-progressdialog/3028660#3028660).

I tried to remake that program, but I got stuck when Android Studio found error

> "cannot resolve symbol 'GroundyTask'"

Also in import statement in `com.telly.groundy.util.Bundler` "telly" has the same problem.

What can I do with that?

Comment: Please include examples in the body of the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the answer you found is obviously using a library named `groundy` which you have not included in the project or have the wrong version of. You can download it [here](https://github.com/telly/groundy).

Note that the readme states it is no longer maintained and recommended to use [RXJava](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava) instead.